# What is a "Doppler instability"?

Tags: physical-chemistry, biophysics, stability, chaos-theory, complex-systems

In the paper ["Flow-induced control of chemical turbulence"](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3656248) by Berenstein and Beta, the term "Doppler instability" is mentioned in the context of the Belousov-Zhabotinsky reaction.

I am looking for a definition of the said instability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking the relevant reference (and iterating once) you arrive at the paper by Qi Ouyang, Harry L. Swinney, and Ge Li, "Transition from Spirals to Defect-Mediated Turbulence Driven by a Doppler Instability" ([Phys. Rev. Lett. 84, 1047](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.84.1047); [e-print 1](http://chaos.ph.utexas.edu/manuscripts/1063306615.pdf), [2](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f1bf/e72b1947b22002ed302d55ae250841864696.pdf)), which describes:

> The observed spiral instability occurs whent he spiral tip meanders and the Doppler effect becomes so large that adjacent waves interact and break, forming defects. [...] As a consequence of the Doppler effect, spiral waves in front of the spiral tip are compressed and spiral waves behind the spiral tip are dilated.

And, in particular:

> The observed phenomena can be well explained by an instability mechanism that was proposed by Bäret al.[10]; we call it the Doppler instability. The behavior of spiral waves in an excitable medium is governed by a dispersion relation that relates the speed to the period of the traveling waves.  In general, the speed of the waves depends on how rapidly the local system recovers its quiescent state after being excited; hence, it is an increasing function of the period of waves [20]. There exists a minimum period $\rho_\text{min}$ below which the system cannot recover to its excitable state, and traveling waves cease to exist [20,21]. Generally, the period of regular spiral waves is larger than the minimum period; thus spiral waves are stable.  However, when a spiral tip meanders, the local period of its waves varies because of the Doppler effect. For sufficiently large meandering, the local period of spiral waves ($\rho_0$) becomes less than $\rho_\text{min}$, rendering the local chemical waves unstable, and defects are spontaneously created.